# Openlayers 4 - Make layer invisible on feature click

Tags: javascript, typescript, openlayers

I have a map with 2 `layer`'s containing `features` (markers). I have made it so that if the map is zoomed in far enough, 1 `layer` will become invisible and the other will become visible (and vise versa). Like this:

```
this.map.getView().on('propertychange', (e: any) => {
  if (e.key == "resolution") {
    if (this.map.getView().getZoom() >= 17) {
      exampleLayer1.setVisible (false);
      exampleLayer2.setVisible (true);
    } else if(this.map.getView().getZoom() < 17) {
      exampleLayer2.setVisible (false);
      exampleLayer1.setVisible (true);
    }
  }
})
```

What I now need to add is that if you click on a `feature` in the `exampleLayer1` layer, the map would zoom in and center on the location of that feature, which would make the `exampleLayer1` disappear and `exampleLayer2` visible. For this, I use this function:

```
var select_interaction = new ol.interaction.Select();

select_interaction.getFeatures().on("add", (e: any) => {
  var feature = e.element;
  this.map.getView().setCenter(feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates())
  this.map.getView().setZoom(17);
});

this.map.addInteraction(select_interaction);
```

Almost everything works fine, meaning one `layer` will disappear and the other will appear. However, the `feature` clicked on will not disappear, even though it's parent (the `layer`) does disappear. If I then click away from the `feature` it will disappear.

How could I make it the `layer` (including the `feature` clicked on) will become invisible when the `feature` is clicked?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ol.interaction.Select selected features are added to an internal unmanaged layer.

This is why the selected feature is visible even if the underlying layer is not.

You could unselect the selected features while you zoom on it using select_interaction.getFeatures().clear() (just like clicking away).

I also suggest you to use layer's min/maxResolutions (see http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.layer.Base.html ) to toggle layers visibility.