# Open Layer: Problem with persistent select interaction feature

Tags: select, cluster-computing, zooming, openlayers, double-click

In my app I had to develop a system that allows the user, with a double click, to zoom in to a cluster.
Everything work, but the problem is that the double click add a feature on the map (a point) and it is persistent (it also replace the feature I selected in case I select not the cluster but the single element, even if I have specified that features.length>=2, so the double click should work only if the user doubles click on the cluster, but it is not like that ).
I would like the select interaction perform only the zoom into the cluster and not that the event adds also a feature on the map. How could I solve this?

```
var selectDoubleClick = new ol.interaction.Select({
   multi: true,
   condition: ol.events.condition.doubleClick,
   layer: this.clusterLayer,
   style: this.selectedClusterStyle
});

selectDoubleClick.on('select',function(event) {
   var eventFeature = event.selected[0];
   var features = eventFeature.get('features');
   if (features.length>=2){
      var extent = ol.extent.createEmpty();
      features.forEach(function(feature) {
               ol.extent.extend(extent, feature.getGeometry().getExtent());
      });
      this.getMap().getView().fit(extent, {padding: [150, 150, 150, 150]})
   }
});
this.map.addInteraction(selectDoubleClick);
```

I also tried to set selectDoubleClick `style:null` but it doesn't solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Follow this discussion, I finally found a solution:

[Openlayers 4 - Make layer invisible on feature click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43998187/openlayers-4-make-layer-invisible-on-feature-click)

In particular:

> The ol.interaction.Select selected features are added to an internal
>   unmanaged layer.
>
> This is why the selected feature is visible even if the underlying
>   layer is not.
>
> You could unselect the selected features while you zoom on it using
>   select_interaction.getFeatures().clear() (just like clicking away).

So I edited my code like that:

```
selectDoubleClick.on('select',function(event) {
     var eventFeature = event.selected[0];
     var features = eventFeature.get('features');
     if (features.length>1){
           var extent = ol.extent.createEmpty();
           features.forEach(function(feature) {
                  ol.extent.extend(extent, feature.getGeometry().getExtent());
           });
           this.getMap().getView().fit(extent, {padding: [150, 150, 150, 150]})
      }else{
            selectDoubleClick.getFeatures().clear()
      }
 });
 this.map.addInteraction(selectDoubleClick);
```